# Change the name of the button based in wordpress plugin upon a category condition

Tags: php, wordpress

The button here states `RSVP`; however, I need it to state `Gift` when a certain category (honeymoon), which is the only category that is relevant,  has been selected.

Currently, it looks like this:

```
<?php if ( ! $campaign->is_endless() ) : ?>
                    <p class="fixed-notice">
                    <?php if ( 'fixed' == $campaign->type() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'This project will only be funded if at least %1$s is pledged by %2$s.', 'crowdpress' ), $campaign->goal(), $end_date ); ?>
                    <?php elseif ( 'flexible' == $campaign->type() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'All funds will be collected on %1$s.', 'crowdpress' ), $end_date ); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'All pledges will be collected automatically until %1$s.', 'crowdpress' ), $end_date ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>

              <p class="button">
                <a href="#pledges" class="button-big"><?php _e('RSVP','crowdpress'); ?></a>
              </p>

            </div>

            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>

        <?php // Calculate Time Left
        $days_left = $campaign->days_remaining();
```

Answer (score 0):

in the button you have the name'RSVP' as a string. If you want to change then it needs to be a variable which is assigned in the if honeymoon is selected

the variable type need to be an string objects name